# Symlink in Laradock return "Invalid Symlink"

Tags: laravel, symlink, laradock

i am trying to create symlink in laravel (laradock) but the result is invalid symlink,

[image]

I have already tried to delete the file and to re-launch the artisan command, I have tried to reset the container but nothing to do, someone could tell me what or how to do? a thousand thanks

Comment: Hello i have the same problem :)) did you manage to find a fix?

Comment: @amepro did you run artisan link command from within your operating system or from within the workspace container?